# check if multiple columns are object type

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm importing an Excel file and when I check the datatype of the pandas series some are `object` and others are `int64`.

I want to find out if any of the columns passed are of `object` type.

When I run:

```
if df['dim_weight'].dtype == object or df['dim_length'].dtype == object or df['dim_height'].dtype == object:
```

and some of the columns are not an object this works as expected but when I do the inverse:

```
if not df['dim_weight'].dtype == object or not df['dim_length'].dtype == object or not df['dim_height'].dtype == object:
```

the check fails. Is there a more efficient way to check for this in Pandas? I ultimately want to check if any of the columns are not a string. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to just select the object columns or do you want to check whether you have any object columns?

Comment: I want to check if the columns are int64 datatype. If they are all int64 then I want to execute a block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in the logic theory, the opposite of `(A or B)` is `(not A) and (not B)`, not `(not A) or (not B)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute `dtypes` of dataframe to get a series containing the datatypes of all columns, then compare the series with `inte64` and reduce with `all` to create a boolean condition:

```
if df.dtypes.eq('int64').all():
    # Execute the statements when condition is True
```